# Import a JavaScript file into another JavaScript file that is imported into another file

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I need to import a file that imports code from another file and then import that file into a final file that adds code to an HTML button. How can I do this? When I try with the following example below no code runs.

```
// file 1
export function someFunction() {
    // more code
}

// file 2
import {someFunction} from './file1';
export function otherFunction() {
    someFunction();
    // more code
}

// file 3
import {otherFunction} from './file2';
document.getElementById('some-button').onclick = otherFunction;

// in index.html 
<script type='module' src='./file3.js'></script>
```

Comment: Do you have script tags for file1 and file2? Otherwise there's no way for `import` to get those files...

Comment: @HereticMonkey They don't need script tags. `import` is able to fetch the imported files by itself. Only the top-level modules have to be included via script tags, and the OP has that.

Comment: The problem is with the import paths: you have to add the extension (`.js`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have all the files be included in the index.html as type="module"

```js
<script type='module' src='./file1.js'></script>
<script type='module' src='./file2.js'></script>
<script type='module' src='./file3.js'></script>
```